# Is there a camera app that supports Sony Remote API over Wifi Direct?

Tags: android, camera, wifi

I just got a used Sony QX1.

The official **Imaging Edge Mobile** app is a bit wonky, but mostly works.

Though the big downside is that to connect to the camera, it creates a hotspot which the phone connects to as a client, so I can't use my normal Internet WiFi at the same time.

I figured out that the hardware actually supports three connection modes:

1. Set camera to [Single] mode, Camera creates hotspot, phone connects as client
2. Set camera to [Single] mode, start a **WiFi Direct** connection from your phone. The camera will beep until you long-press the WiFi button on it.
3. Set camera to [Multi] mode, press the WPS button on your router (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820594/1872399)

Apparently Imaging Edge Mobile only supports 1). Is there any alternative available?